# jQuery replaceWith() displaces inner text/html of replacement

Tags: jquery

I'm using replaceWith() to replace a link with another link with a different onchange and an internal span tag, like so:

```
$(a.class).replaceWith("<a onclick='return ajax_spam(this);' /><span>Unflag as Spam</span></a>");
```

This works except for the span tag is placed after the closing  tag. Same happens if I replace the span tag with just text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ***prematurely*** closing the `a` tag...

**change:**

`<a onclick='return ajax_spam(this);' /><span>Unflag as Spam</span></a>`

**to:**

`<a onclick='return ajax_spam(this);' ><span>Unflag as Spam</span></a>`